# Need help converting a basic valid JSON string object (from db) into a PHP object using json_decode

Tags: php, jsondecodeerror

I am having trouble converting a basic valid JSON string object into a PHP object using json_decode (it shows as null).
I have tried several things but so far still not working. I'm sure I am missing something simple but I could use help getting this going. This seems to be an issue about the JSON string that is coming directly from the database (text field) - possibly something related to escaping characters or something?

basic json string in database (text field) :

```
{"address":"111 main street","id":"1","name":"test","phone":"888 888 8888","zip":"123"}
```

PHP

```
$jsonobj = $dbfield;
echo $jsonobj
```

on page display is:

```
string(187) "{"address":"111 main street","id":"1","name":"test","phone":"888 888 8888","zip":"123"}"
var_dump($jsonobj);
```

on page display is:

```
string(187) "{"address":"111 main street","id":"1","name":"test","phone":"888 888 8888","zip":"123"}"
php
var_dump(json_decode($jsonobj));
```

on page display is:
`NULL` - why?
php
`var_dump(html_entity_decode($jsonobj));`
on page display is:
`string(87) "{"address":"111 main street","id":"1","name":"test","phone":"888 888 8888","zip":"123"}"`
this works when i create hard coded var...

```
$js = '{"address":"111 main street","id":"1","name":"test","phone":"888 888 8888","zip":"123"}';
$obj = json_decode($js);
echo $obj->address;
```

display works

111 main street

Can anyone shed some light on converting what looks like valid json from the database to php object?

Comment: Notice the character count `187` vs the actual character count, which is about 88. You have some invisible characters breaking your json string. This may be from when you're inserting it into the database

Comment: Thanks for the help. As it turns out – I needed to use both html_entity_decode and json_decode to get this working like this:

$jsonobj = json_decode( html_entity_decode($dbfield));

Thanks for the help - Dave

Comment: You should not have applied HTML encoding to the data that was inserted into the data base, in the first place. This should happen when you _output_ the data into an HTML context.